# Align position absolute element to the end of the relative element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a position absolute element which has a min-width. What I want to do is to align the absolute element's end to the relative element's end.

[image]

The relative element DOES NOT have a fixed width. The width can be vary depending on the content inside.

The use case here is, I'm building a custom dropdown. The relative element is the label which has the selected text and the position absolute element is the dropdown.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">Text from list</div>
 <ul class="list">...</ul>
</div>
```

The image above has the look I'm expecting. What should I do to get this alignment? Can it be done with pure CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.relative-div {
 position:relative;
 min-height: 50px;
 background:#BB9A9B;
}
.abs-div {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
    top: calc(100% + 10px);
 min-width: 100px;
 min-height: 50px;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="relative-div">
 relative-div
  <div class="abs-div"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg. I was doing all kinds of things except this. Thank you.

Comment: I would set the vertical value from the top, rather than the bottom though ... if `.abs-div` grows longer, it will overlap `.relative-div`, because you're compensating for the height of the absolute positioned element only if there is one element. OP states that it will be a list of items. `top: calc(100% + 10px)` would work, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
.element {
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
    border: 1px solid navy;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.parent-class {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

.relative-element {
    position: relative;
 }

.absolute-element {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 200px;
    right: 0px;
}

    <div class="parent-class">
      <div class="element relative-element">Relative Element</div>
      <div class="element absolute-element">Absolute Element</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Here is the link to the code as well: https://codepen.io/POULIMA/pen/LQJZqY

Answer (score -3):

i would recommend to use flex-box. here is a cheat-sheet https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This is not about display but position.